# File upload validation using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form filed as follows

```
<span> Upload CV :</span><input type="file" id="flu"  name="filename" />
```

And am calling Validation function as follows

```
<form name="frm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onsubmit = "return validateForm()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Validitaion function is as follows

```
else if (document.forms["frm"].filename.value == null ||  document.forms["frm"].filename.value== "") {
             document.getElementById("fullnameerr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("subspecerr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("emailerr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("mobileerr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("pperr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("dateerr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("currentworkerr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("filenameerr").innerHTML="Please upload your CV";
             document.forms["frm"].filename.focus();
        return false;
        }

  else if (document.forms["frm"].captcha.value == null ||  document.forms["frm"].captcha.value== "") {
             document.getElementById("fullnameerr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("subspecerr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("emailerr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("mobileerr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("pperr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("dateerr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("currentworkerr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("filenameerr").innerHTML="";
             document.getElementById("captchatxterr").innerHTML="Please enter image text";
             document.forms["frm"].captcha.focus();
           return false;
        }
  else  {
        return true;
        }
```

How can I validate file upload to check file size for 1 MB and it should submit .doc and .pdf documents any help may greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, if you want to validate your form (size/extensions) this can help you: https://deepeshdarshan.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/how-to-validate-upload-file-size-and-file-extension-using-javascript/

Comment: Example is good but, how can I integrate with my code as am newbie please post some code

Comment: I tried the code that you provided link, By changing function as follows   <form name="frm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"onsubmit ="return !!(validateForm() & validation(this));" enctype="multipart/form-data">  but, no luck